# javax.jmdns lib is not getting imported.How to make the error clear?

Tags: java, android, networking, jmdns

These imports are showing error

```
import javax.jmdns.JmmDNS;
import javax.jmdns.NetworkTopologyDiscovery;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceEvent;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceInfo;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceListener;
import javax.jmdns.impl.NetworkTopologyDiscoveryImpl;
```

How to clear those errors

Comment: Android does not have those classes. Most likely, you will need to find some other solution to whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need them, just delete those lines.

If you do need them, import what you need.

Go to your build.gradle (module:app) and under "dependencies" add the libraries you need.

```
dependencies {

    // Android support
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:percent:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

}
```

You can also search for those libraries in the Maven Repository.

Here's the example for your first import:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jmdns/jmdns/3.2.2

Under the "Gradle" tab you can see that you can import it by writing:

```
implementation group: 'javax.jmdns', name: 'jmdns', version: '3.2.2'
```